# Вылезает ошибка:TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not int.Помогите исправить

Tags: python

---

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dino")

cactus_img = [pygame.image.load("кактус 0.png"), pygame.image.load("кактус 1.png"), 
pygame.image.load("кактус 2.png")]
cactus_option = [28, 430, 35, 430, 55, 449]
```

---

```
class Cactus():

def __init__(self, x ,y, width, speed, image):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.wigth = width
    self.speed = speed
    self.image = image

def move(self):
    if self.x >= self.wigth:
        display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
    # pygame.draw.rect(display, (255, 10, 25), (self.x, self.y, self.wigth, self.height))
        self.x -= self.speed
        return True
    else:
        self.x = display_width -50
        return False

def return_self(self, radius, y, width, image):
    self.x = radius
    self.y = y
    self.wigth = width
    self.image = image
    display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

---

```
user_width = 60
user_height = 100
user_x = display_width // 3
user_y = display_height - user_height - 100

cactus_width = 30
cactus_height = 80
cactus_x = display_width - 50
cactus_y = display_height - cactus_height - 100

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

make_jump = False
jump_counter = 30
```

---

```
def run_game():
    global make_jump
    game = True
    land = pygame.image.load('поле.png')
    cactus_arr = []
    create_cactus_arr(cactus_arr)

    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            make_jump = True

        if make_jump:
            jump()


        display.blit(land, (0, 0))
        draw_array(cactus_arr)


        pygame.draw.rect(display, (00, 255, 00), (user_x, user_y, user_width, user_height))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)
```

---

```
def jump():
    global user_y, jump_counter, make_jump
    if jump_counter >= -28 :
        user_y -= jump_counter // 3
        jump_counter -= 1
    else:
        jump_counter = 30
        make_jump = False
```

---

```
def create_cactus_arr(array):
    choice = random.randrange(0, 3)
    img = cactus_img[choice]
    width = cactus_option[choice * 2]
    height = cactus_option[choice * 2 + 1]
    array.append(Cactus(display_width - 50, height, width, img, 3))

    choice = random.randrange(0, 3)
    img = cactus_img[choice]
    width = cactus_option[choice * 2]
    height = cactus_option[choice * 2 + 1]
    array.append(Cactus(display_width + 200, height, width, img, 3))

    choice = random.randrange(0, 3)
    img = cactus_img[choice]
    width = cactus_option[choice * 2]
    height = cactus_option[choice * 2 + 1]
    array.append(Cactus(display_width + 500, height, width, img, 3))
```

---

```
def find_radius(array):
    maximum = max(array[0].x, array[1].x ,array[2].x)

    if maximum < display_width:
        radius = display_width
        if radius - maximum < 50:
            radius += 150
    else:
        radius = maximum

    choice = random.randrange(0, 5)
    if choice == 0:
        radius += random.randrange(10, 15)
    else:
        radius += random.randrange(200, 350)

    return radius
```

---

```
def draw_array(array):
    for cactus in array:
        check = cactus.move()
        if not check:
            radius = find_radius(array)

            choice = random.randrange(0, 3)
            img = cactus_img[choice]
            width = cactus_option[choice * 2]
            height = cactus_option[choice * 2 + 1]

            cactus.return_self(radius, height, width, img)
```

---

```
run_game()
```

---

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 0):

В create_cactus_arr (в array.append(Cactus(...))) ты перепутал speed и img (сравни то что ты передаешь в класс Cactus, и что он должен принимать)